# HASH ASP.net Coookie created without HTTPONLY flag

Tags: asp.net, cookies

In our solution, we have the appropriate configs set to flag as both SECURE and HTTPONLY as one would expect. During our first PEN tests we passed and all is well. We regularly do PEN tests even when no code has been updated and in the second pass-through we failed out of the blue. In reviewing the issue we failed because there are relatively 2 sets of cookies created by .net. The standard Session and ASPnetAuth cookies are both flagged as secure and HttpOnly as one would expect. And then there is a HASH version of those same cookies that is only flagged as SECURE.

Now at first glance and remembering the patch notes for .net 4 this hash is the machine key hash provided by forms authentication. At least that is my assumption, I have failed to find any documentation on MSDN outlining the purpose of these HASH version of the cookies. And because of this I naturally do not understand why they are only flagged Secured and not flagged HTTPONLY, and without any knowledge or documentation from MSDN I fail to have the appropriate response on if we do, indeed, have a vulnerability issue.

Does anyone have any details about this version of the cookie and if this has any vulnerabilities?